# Error on performing actions with a complex number represented by capital I

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am relatively new to Python and have encountered a strange issue. I need to calculate a thickness of a tube 't' out of the eqn. which is given below. As expected, "solution" gives 4 possible values of t, of which only one is feasible, being a positive and real value. Two of my four solutions are complex and one is negative. Out of my solution-array of 4 values, I want to take that specific feasible solution and one operation is taking the real part of all values in that array. In taking the real part of one complex solution (sol2.real) out of the solution-array, it gives me always an error, while taking x.real with eg. x=1+2j gives the expected 1. I have noticed that my complex solutions don't have the normal symbol j, but the capital symbol I. The numpy and sympy packages are imported.

```
import numpy
import simpy

sigma_max=880000000
r_i=0.06
t = Symbol('t')
eqn=sigma_max-((9000*5.5*9.81)/(3.1415*((r_i+t)**2-r_i**2)))-(r_i+t)* \
(((25000*0.5*9.81)**2+(134*9.81)**2)**0.5)/((3.1415/4)*((r_i+t)**4-r_i**4))
solution=solve(eqn, t)
print(solution)
sol2=solution[2]
x=1+2j
print(x.real)
print(sol2.real)
```

The error I encounter with the "print(sol2.real)" command is:

```
'Add' object has no attribute 'real'
```

Could someone explain me what my fault is or where it goes wrong?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your `eqn` line has a syntax error in it, which means nobody can run your code to debug it without first trying to guess what you wanted and fix it. (You can't have a newline in an expression unless it's inside parentheses.) And there's no such library as `simpy`. And you're using `Symbol` without importing it (you probably wanted `sympy.Symbol`). Please post a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: A backslash for line continuation "fixes" the syntax error; deleting the trailing back-quote fixes another.  There is, too a package "simpy" -- I just installed it.  However, the lack of the `Symbol` class leaves the program DOA.

Comment: @Prune Yeah, there are actually at least two projects named `simpy`… but neither one of them is a symbolic computation library with names like `Symbol` and `solve`…

Comment: @abarnert I'm very sorry about the errors, I copy-pasted it from my python script and forgot about the library error. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your actual code is doing something reasonable, your problem is that you're mixing up sympy expressions with normal Python numbers.

Your `sol2` is an expression. Sure, it *looks* like a number, but that's true for any expression that has nothing but constant values in it; it's still not a Python `complex`, any more than `sympy.pi` is a Python `float`.

What you probably want here is the [`re`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#re) function:

```
>>> print(sympy.re(sol2))
-0.0720141606282290
```

(Of course this still isn't a Python `float`, it's still a `sympy` expression. But it prints out what I think you want to print out.)

---

Or, if you're done doing symbolic computation and want to convert to raw Python values, you can do that this:

```
>>> print(float(sympy.re(sol2)))
-0.07201416062822902
>>> print(complex(sol2).re)
-0.07201416062822902
```

Either of these *is* getting a Python `float`—along with any rounding errors that come from converting an exact symbolic value, or higher-precision decimal value, to `float`, of course.

Comment: That makes it perfectly clear, I got confused between the number & expression, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the items in `solution` are classes of sympy (e.g. `type(solution[2])` is `<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>`, which doesn't have an attribute `real`.

You can fix this by changing `print(sol2.real)` to `print(complex(sol2).real)`